# Are edit suggestions appropriate for addressing factual accuracy?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, wrong-answers

I am aware that we should not **flag** inaccurate answers, we should only flag non-answers, completely off-topic answers, link-only or otherwise very low quality answers, and of course, spam and rude/abusive answers.

But we should **downvote** wrong answers and/or leave a comment explaining why they are wrong.

However, would it be acceptable to **suggest an edit** that corrects the inaccuracies of the answer, or would this most likely be rejected for *'This edit deviates from the original intent of the post?'*

**Note: This is primarily about answers, but if a question includes a false statement or assumption, this question applies there too.**

Comment: it depends on the edit.

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34008906

Comment: I would be uncomfortable approving the first one, but i wouldn't fault an SME for approving it or making it under the assumption they're correct and not removing information that might be useful for older versions.

Comment: _**but if a question includes a false statement or assumption**_ that should be rather stated in comments, to allow greater agreement from the community, rather than the people active at the edit Suggestion queue.

Comment: I'd suggest you consider more leniency towards questions. More often than not the wrong assumption getting addressed in an answer is what solves the problem! In which case the Q&A is a very useful pair of posts detailing the **correct** statement.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are not supposed to change the meaning of the original answer. The original author's name is displayed under the post and you should not be "putting words into their mouth".

You are free to correct any mistakes you see in an answer as long as the meaning remains the same. However, if the answer is fundamentally flawed or incorrect, you should downvote and provide an alternative answer.

When editing questions, do not correct technical mistakes as they could be important to the question asked. Fix only spelling, grammar or layout mistakes. You can rewrite questions **if and only if** you are positively sure that you know what the original author meant and your edit does not change or invalidate existing answers. Fixing mistakes in the question should be done by providing a respective answer instead.

Comment: While indeed it is correct answer (up) but unfortunately this policy makes it very frustrating to look at highly upvoted obsolete or otherwise wrong answers as there is absolutely nothing practical can be done to fix those - no way to get enough downvotes, no edits allowed and no flagging either...  As usual - the real option is to seek professional help if you have strong feeling when none expected :).

Comment: The "Trending" sort should help in that case, but then, the problem is that some users do not vote at all...

Comment: I continue to fail, utterly, to understand why anyone thinks this policy is at all a good one.

Comment: This is probably the most reasonable statement of the policy that I've seen, @Karl. I think preserving the intent of the author is a good principle. However, it needs to be applied in a way that is reasonable. If I end up posting an answer with code that contains a bug, the most reasonable assumption is that *it's a bug*, which means that it was not my intention to post a wrong answer, which means that it should be fixed. However, if my *entire answer* is something which you think is wrong, then that shouldn't be "fixed" with an edit that rewrites it, because I probably meant what I said.

Comment: Yes, it's well-stated. I just strongly disagree. I think that preserving the author's intent is incompatible with creating "a library of detailed, high-quality answers". Incorrect answers cannot be high quality. Above and beyond the part where popular misconceptions can get popular support, a lot of people who *do* generally understand a concept can introduce a lot of ancillary inaccuracies that probably genuinely do reflect their mental model. More commonly, people will just blatantly misuse terminology even though they "know how it works".